# Get time (GMT) from 1970 by seconds in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I just need to get the (GMT) time by seconds from 1970

i found this method

```
 NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

but its return the time depends on device time not ( GMT ) time

Comment: Its return time does not depend on local time — you've drawn a false inference. It works exactly as documented, providing "The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC* on 1 January 1970. (read-only)". Why do you believe otherwise? (* GMT for this purpose)

Comment: yea thanks for your comment i got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970), it does exactly what you want (UTC is equivalent to GMT in this scope):

> The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970

`NSDate` represents an instant in time and is independent of time zones:

> `NSDate` objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone

Time zones are only used to print the instant in time as a human readable string

Comment: but how i tried to print the value 


Thanks i was confused ! 
when i printed it i got the time that i need thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the right code. From doc of `timeIntervalSince1970`

> The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January
>   1970. (read-only) This property’s value is negative if the date object is earlier than 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i got it :)